# ASP.NET Master page with Menus and Content page with data entry form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a web site wherein I need to have different menus for different set of users. Hence created master pages for these users and displaying menus for them.

In the content page I use a dropdownlist boxes  with data populated in this page's code behind.  I use a public class & structure to load data

Now when i click on one of the DDL (upon OnSelectedIndexChanged event), the already loaded structure becomes empty. I tried checking PostBack...but still when the Page Load of Master page ocvurs, the structures become empty.

Pl support.

Comment: can you share a code snipping at least? thanks.

Comment: are you sure you are referring to the same master page?

Comment: Yes. In the content page, I am using a class to retrieve data, and this class is called from the Page Load event of the content page.

Comment: Since you are using Masterpage/Contentpage, you should create your menubar as a CONTROL and place it in the Masterpage.

Then you populate the menu when the masterpage initialises/loads

Comment: @Zeddy, I have already placed the menu in the master page and is working good.  In the content page (of this master page) I have placed three DDLs.  I am using a separate class to retrieve the DB entries using Collection and adding onto these DDLs, on the Page_Load of the content page (of course, am checking AutoPostBack).  Upto this is working good and I can see the values in the DDLs.  But if I run OnSelectedIndexChanged event on any one of the DDL, then the already stored details on the Collections are lost and the count is shown as 0 after Page_Load of Master Page is executed

Comment: Post the relevant portions of your code, maybe another member may spot something, both the serverside code and the page xhtml /html code, Also where do you call the external public class from? The masterpage or the content page? if its executing from the page_load event of the contentpage it should be fine, if you are keeping count of something, where have you scoped your counter(s)? at the masterpage level or contentpage level? When you post code, it saves other members from trying to understand the question fully in the right context

Comment: Public Class DealerAdminMaster
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Public oRegion As New clsRegion, oDealer As New clsDealer, Regions As New List(Of clsRegion.Regions), Dealers As New List(Of clsDealer.Dealer)
    Public Shared ldealers As New List(Of clsDealer.Dealer)
    Public Shared lRegions As New List(Of clsRegion.Regions)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Regions = oRegion.getRegions()
            Dealers = oDealer.getDealers()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: In the PreRender event of Content Page:

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            PopulateRegions()  --- to place the data onto the DDL
        End If

DDL-OnSelectedIndexChanged Event (on the content Page):

Protected Sub cboRegion_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If cboRegion.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Session("RegionID") = Master.Regions(cboRegion.SelectedIndex).RegionID
            PopulateDealers(Session("RegionID"))
        End If
End Sub

Here the content of Master.Regions is empty and throwing exception